# Subversion - put version number in a file

Tags: svn, deployment, revision

I just want a single file, called "revision", which contains the repository revision number at any given time so that when I **export** my repository, my application is able to see which revision it was.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using normal Keyword Substitution is that `$rev$` only shows the last revision in which that file changed. I haven't tried it myself, but there is a tool called `svnversion` that comes with SVN that I believe you can use to get the revision number of the working copy. It's then just a case of configuring your build process to use this tool and insert the result into your revision file.

There is a good guide on how to use `svnversion` (especially if you're using ANT) here: http://cameronstokes.com/2009/12/12/using-svnversion-from-ant

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something using pre-commit hook, but I don't really know if that's such a great idea.

Why don't you version your app on its own? (and eg. put version number in the commit comment)
Wouldn't that be a simpler solution?

What is more svn revision numbers are given one by one no matter what branch it's being committed to - is this ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this out.  We used to do this with CVS.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Comment: Normal keyword substitution won't work as it only shows when that file was last updated. Half way down the page, in the yellow box called "Where's $GlobalRev$?", it explains why and mentions "svnversion" - this is what you need.